# ¿Hay diferencia entre jpg y JPG?

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, hosting

Tengo en mi servidor web archivos con extensión jpg y algunos otros con JPG (no confundir con JPEG o jpeg), según el conocimiento que tengo ambas extensiones jpg-JPG son lo mismo, pero cuando en mi servidor web muestro las imágenes me sale error, por ejemplo:

---

Si coloco esto:
https://miweb.com/sist/uploads/imagenes/la-imagen.JPG Esta bien

Pero si coloco esto: https://miweb.com/sist/uploads/imagenes/la-imagen.jpg Esta mal

---

¿Ambas no son lo mismo?

Es la primera vez que me ocurre este problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te está funcionando correctamente. Los sistemas de archivo habituales en Unix son case-sensitive por defecto.

En realidad un archivo la-imagen.jpg es diferente a otro que se llame la-imagen.JPG o LA-IMAGEN.JPG.

Deberías acceder a él por la ruta en la que esté subido al servidor.

Comment: En si funciona correctamente, siempre y cuando lleve el JPG o jpg correspondiente, pero ahora me haces recordar lo del case-sensitive y entiendo que el servidor es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, lo raro es que anteriormente en otros servidores web online no había tenido ese problema, ni en el localhost tampoco (XAMPP en Windows).

Comment: Como bien dices, eso ocurría en Windows. En caso de usar FAT32, es case-insensitive. Si usas NTFS, internamente trabaja de manera case-sensitive, pero Windows "facilita" al usuario deshabilitándolo.

Comment: Excelente aclaración y recordatorio, a la vez gracias por compartir tu conocimiento.

Answer (score 3):

En sistemas windows es imposible tener dos archivos o carpetas al mismo nivel con el mismo nombre.

Esto quiere decir que, en un mismo directoro windows, `imagen.jpg` y `imagen.JPG` NO pueden existir juntas, mientras que en sistemas linux o unix `imagen.jpg` e `imagen.JPG` son diferentes archivos y pueden convivir juntas en el mismo directorio.

Lo mismo te pasará con aquellos archivos que contengan caracteres especiales, por ejemplo `imágen.jpg` o con `imagen(1).jpg`